# датафрейм из листа

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть лист:

```
test = ['1','start1','2','3','end','4','5','start2','6','end']
```

хочу сделать из него датафрейм

| INDEX | Column |
| --- | --- |
| start1 | 2,3 |
| start2 | 6 |

Comment: Ну, перебирайте элементы, старты складывайте в один список, остальное после старта и до энда в другой список, потом создаёте датафрейм из этих двух списков.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.

```
import re

str_of = ', '.join([i for i in test])
a = re.findall("start\d*, (.*?), end", str_of)
b = re.findall("start\d*", str_of)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=b, columns=['column'])

>>> df

        column
start1   2, 3
start2      6
```